# Selecting Word from Array of Words in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select some words out of an array of words.
For example, the array is like below:

```
var list = ['Brothers', 'Browsers', 'Dermatologist','Specialist','Optometry']
```

I use below script to perform selection

```
var pattern = "Der";
var matched = list.filter(a => a.indexOf(pattern) >= 0);
```

The **matched** variable will contains:

```
['Dermatologist']
```

But when I change the **pattern** variable value to **"ist**" the result would be

```
['Dermatologist','Specialist']
```

I want my filtering to works only matching from the beginning of every word. So if I set **pattern** variable value to **"Bro"** it will returns

```
['Brothers','Browsers']
```

But when I set **pattern** variable value to **"ers"** it will returns empty array

[]

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want. Maybe you need `startsWith` or `endsWith` methods on String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `startsWith`

```js
var list = ['Brothers', 'Browsers', 'Dermatologist','Specialist','Optometry']

var pattern = "Der";
var matched = list.filter(a => a.startsWith(pattern));

console.log(matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with `^` (which means beginning of line) before the pattern:

```js
var list = ['Brothers', 'Browsers', 'Dermatologist','Specialist','Optometry'];

var pattern = /^Bro.*/;

var matched = list.filter(a => pattern.test(a));

console.log(matched);
```